# Creating a helix look for a marble track

Tags: modifiers

Hi The following [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8u2fmgk4njzpkl/Helix.blend?dl=0) shows how I created my loop. If is built from a base object that I will use to build the rest of the track. I am wanting to pull the ends of the loop apart in the direction of the arrows so that I can create a simple helix loop.

I tried dragging the end faces using proportional editing but it lands up pulling both ends in the same direction.

I tried using a curve modifier too but could not get it right.

[image: Moving the ends to create a loop for a marble track]

Comment: Hello :). If you don't need the segments separated, you can achieve this easily using the *Screw modifier*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to go about accomplishing this would be to use an Array modifier on a single segment of your track. Make sure the origin of your track segment is at 0,0,0. Position the track segment in edit mode to the outside of your helix.

[image]

Create an array modifier on your track segment object using the Object Offset mode. Create an empty to use as the target object.

[image]

The basic deal is that every transform you apply to your empty gets applied between every iteration of the array. So, I rotate the empty 15° (360/24, the number of segments) about the Y axis. Then I moved the empty very slightly along the y-axis to create your helix effect.

[image]

The attached file contains the basic set-up. In my demo I used the merge options in the array to create a seamless loop. You can use the same principle if you want each segment to be disconnected. You will likely have to rotate your track segments very slightly about the z-axis in edit mode if you do in order for them to line up, or you will get this kind of stepping effect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Rekov. It is exactly what I was looking for but I can't seem to get it right: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gr5ze16bdj3h5t1/HelixObjectDemo-fail.blend?dl=0. Could you please take a look and let me know what I am missing

Comment: Ok so I am getting closer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mmjzo0axok9igg/Helix2.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hey @ABasel Your problem is that the origin of your cube channel object is not at the right place. You can fix this by selecting it in Object mode, then hit CTRL+A > Apply location. There are a lot of videos on youtube that show how to make a circle array in blender which might help more than  I can by text.